# Angular 7 go offline?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to *turn off* all *buttons*, *click*, *hyperlinks* and put a backdrop with a message to **"GO ONLINE"**. I know it's a bit rude but it's the need.

**AppComponent (TS):** connectionMonitor can be subscribed to observe network connectivity.

```
  private onlineObserver(){
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      const offline$ = fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(mapTo(false));
      const online$ = fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(mapTo(true));
      this.connectionMonitor = merge( offline$, online$ );
    } else {
      this.connectionMonitor = empty();
    }
  }
```

**app.component.html :** Just the *whole router-outlet.*

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> How to achieve this with **Angular 7**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the online flag on your router outlet with an ngIf

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="online$ | async else offline"></router-outlet>
<ng-template #offline>
  content here displays when not online
</ng-template>
```

or

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="online$ | async"></router-outlet>
<ng-container *ngIf="offline$ | async">
  content here displays when offline
</ng-container>
```

Comment: There is a problem with your ngIf solution. this will fire up unnecessary lifecycle hooks. Plus that would be a rendering overhead.

Comment: Rubbish, ngIfs are used all over Angular apps.

Answer (score -1):

`ngIf="offline$ | async` <- put that on the element to show when offline

`ngIf="online$ | async` <- put that on the element to show when online

If you need to still show the controls but have them be inactive, you could use an `ng-template` to load different templates based on whether you're offline. where the offline elements have no click events bound, no hrefs, no pointer events, etc. This question is pretty broad so it's difficult to drill into more detail about your usecase based on the information you've provided.

Comment: There is a problem with your ngIf solution. this will fire up unnecessary lifecycle hooks. Plus that would be a rendering overhead.

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava please elaborate on why that is

Comment: Because he doesn't understand what he is talking about, ngIf is the bread an butter of Angular template development.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I was aiming for a more socratic-method way of teaching ;)

Comment: I have no idea what this is meant to mean.

Comment: @AdrianBrand It means I agree with you, but I was hoping to lead him to questioning his own assumptions instead of stating flat-out "no, you're wrong".

Comment: Well somethings a statement like, ngIf is a rendering overhead needs to be put in it's place.

Comment: Ok so seeing your confidence. I have tested your method. And to my surprise I was right. When you rule out any dom element using ngIf, it's regenerated when it's needed. Even the constructor is called again.

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava of course it is. That's how it's supposed to work. This isn't considered a rendering overhead because it's called _as needed_, not on every tick. You could set an `ngStyle` for `display:none` or `display:block` to avoid regenerating the component, but this could lead to issues with somoene editing the frontend styles with a web inspector (and making the components visible that are supposed to be unavailable), so it's better to use `ngIf` here. Angular will even warn you if you're doing this wrong with a viewchecked error: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Comment: I need to turn off all buttons, click, hyperlinks and put a backdrop with a message to "GO ONLINE" not destroy the DOM. That is the question.

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava and I answered how to do that in my original answer, as well as explaining the potential pitfalls with that approach. I can't help you further.